# focus element when redirect through url jQuery

Tags: html, css

I have a list of elements and I need when redirect focus an element through url.

```
  <div id="20"></div>
  <div id="21"></div>
  <div id="22"></div>

  // url
  http://localhost:8080/#21

  var current_url = window.location.href;
  // Capture the string after #
  var id = current_url.substr(current_url.indexOf("#") + 1);
  $('#'+ id).css('border', '1px solid rgb(204, 255, 248)');
```

With the previous code jQuery select the element with id 21;

but when the url it does not have # show the next error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #http://localhost:8000/admin/dashboard
```

how do I solve it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `location.hash` instead.

```
var id = location.hash;

if (id)
{
  $(id).css('border', '1px solid rgb(204, 255, 248)')
}
```

The reason you have an error because it returns the entire url if there is no hash where it contains special characters jquery doesn't recognize

**OR**

check for hash before proceeding

```
if (location.href.indexOf("#") != 1)
{
  // stuff 
}
```

hope that helps